# I'm trying to delete the rows selected with checkboxes with php code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete the rows selected with checkboxes with php code.
html part

```
<form action="maincontrol.php" name="control" method="post">
<?php
require('dbconnect.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM soru");

echo "<table border='1' id='tumveriler'>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Index</th>
<th>Soru</th>
<th>Sorma Tarih</th>
<th>Cevap</th>
<th>Cevaplama Tarih</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name='checkbox' type='checkbox' value='" . $row['index'] . "'" . " />";
  echo "<td>" . $row['index'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['soru'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['sormadate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cevap'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cevapdate'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);

?>
<input type= "submit" name ="update" value="Update">
</form>
```

php part

```
<?php
  require('dbconnect.php');

  if (isset($_POST['control']) && !empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {

    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $id) 

    {
        $query = "DELETE FROM soru WHERE `index` = '$id'";
        $link = mysql_query($query);

    if(!$link)
        {
        die('not worked: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        else
        {
        mysql_close($con);  
        echo 'worked';
        }


    }
  }

?>
```

When I click update button I see a beautiful white screen. Nothing happens, no error dialogs... Help!

Comment: Your form doesn't see to include an `input` named "control" yet the PHP that's handling the delete has `isset($_POST['control'])`. The `if` statement most likely fails. Also the `input` for the checkboxes should include square brackets to tell PHP it's an array: `<input name="checkbox[]" ... />`.

Comment: @Francois Deschenes What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: In your form, change the line that echoes the checkbox to `echo "<td>" . "<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='" . $row['index'] . "'" . " />";` and if your form doesn't include a field named "control", remove `isset($_POST['control'])` from the `if` statement that in the script that deletes.

Comment: @Francois Deschenes Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'll post an answer below so you can approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- Your code is checking for the existence of `$_POST['control']` which does not exist in the form (at least in the part you posted)
- If you want the checkbox data to be submitted as an array you need to use array notation for the form:

  `<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" ...etc`

otherwise only the last element that was checked will get submitted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that the form was posted, instead of using `isset($_POST['control'])`(which isn't sent),

use

`isset($_POST['update'])` because the submit button IS sent.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned once your checkbox values are an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" ...
```

You can also simplify your database query to delete all the records with a single query using the WHERE IN clause:

```
//  Input filtering - retrieve only int values from $_POST['checkbox']
$array = array_filter($_POST['checkbox'],'is_int');

//  Format array for SQL WHERE IN clause
$array = implode(',',$array);

$query = "DELETE FROM `soru` WHERE `index` IN ($array)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution, as per the comments above:

Your form doesn't see to include an input named "control" yet the PHP that's handling the delete has `isset($_POST['control'])`. The `if` statement most likely fails. Also the input for the checkboxes should include square brackets to tell PHP it's an array: `<input name="checkbox[]" ... />`.

In your form, change the line that echoes the checkbox to `echo "<td>" . "<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='" . $row['index'] . "'" . " />";` and if your form doesn't include a field named "control", remove `isset($_POST['control'])` from the `if` statement that in the script that deletes.